# How to access Internet from within AndEngine - Android

Tags: android, android-webview, andengine, httpconnection, android-networking

It's a straightforward question, but one I haven't been able to figure out: How can I access the internet from an application that utilizes AndEngine (AnalogOnScreenControls). My Activity extends `BaseGameActivity`. Specifically, I want to open a URL connection. All I need to do is execute the URL; I don't want to view it in any way. Should I do it through a `WebView`, `HTTPConnection`, `openStream()` -- what? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved! I had to run all network operations on a thread separate from the main one (else it will throw a NetworkOnMainThread exception). I don't know why nothing else worked, but this did the trick! Here I'm creating a new thread with the action I want to perform, and then starting it after exceptions are taken care of. I found my answer [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("your_url");
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri address = Uri.parse("http://your.link.com");
Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
yourActivity.startActivity(openlink);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I actually solved this a little while ago; I should probably show how I solved it... Your suggestion also works though! (if one is okay with a new browser being opened)